# Handling return key tap with custom text input UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've implemented a custom input UIView based on UILabel. It implements UIKeyInput and UITextInputTraits protocols. So it can handle input and customise keyboard type.

But how to handle keyboard **return key** (Done, Next, etc.) tap within this component? In other words, how does UITextField know when to call textFieldShouldReturn of its delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding custom action when the **return key** is pressed:

```
- (void)insertText:(NSString *)theText
{  
    if ([theText isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        //Here you can implement your own custom action
    } 
}
```

For setting the type of the **return key**:

```
-(UIReturnKeyType) returnKeyType
{
    return UIReturnKeySearch;
}
```